How do i save a file from a pythonista script to iCloud drive
I have a script that used to upload a CSV file to drop-box, so that i could import that file from another IOS app (accounts pro).
I never updated the script to support the newest version of the protocol, and I was thinking to use icloud because "accounts pro" also supports icloud.
So, what is the path that I should use to copy a file to my icloud drive?

I tried to copy a file to ~/Documents/iCloud/Pythonista/ but when i open the Files.app it doesn't show the new file in the folder Pythonista.

found the solution in: https://www.thegeekblog.co.uk/the-geek-blog/2022/6/12/icloud-location-for-pythonista
/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~omz-software~Pythonista3/Documents/
